# NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267]

Tags: python, json, windows, unity-game-engine

This is my code but I code the below error, what is the problem?

```
 input_folder = r'D:\\unity projects\\ACCAD\\ACCAD\\Female1General_c3d'
 output_folder = r'D:\\unity projects\\ACCAD\\ACCAD\\Female1General_c3d_converted'
```

Error:

```
    Processing folder: A10_-_lie_to_crouch_stageii.npz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".\Npzconveter.py", line 18, in <module>
        for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'D:\\\\unity
 projects\\\\ACCAD\\\\ACCAD\\\\Female1General_c3d\\A10_-_lie_to_crouch_stageii.npz'
```

I almost tried everything :( I really appreciate any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

simply use single slash:

```
 input_folder = r'D:\unity projects\ACCAD\ACCAD\Female1General_c3d'
 output_folder = r'D:\unity projects\ACCAD\ACCAD\Female1General_c3d_converted
```

'